# what programming languages are used for making medium sized softwares?

Tags: programming-languages, finalcut

please excuse the stupidity of my question..

Things like Adobe After Effects, Apple final cut, Pro tools, photoshop..
also, things like Windows media player, real player

What programming languages are used to build those?

I'm really interested in knowing, Thanks

Comment: I note you changed the title, but *size* of application is not really a primary deciding factor in language selection. Except perhaps for the fact that programming a large application in 100% assembler is unlikely due to the maintainability, portability, and sheer hard work involved, and scripting languages are often aimed at, and ideally suited to small chunks of integration code, gluing other components together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look up many major applications in Wikipedia, they will have a side-box providing information including the development language (where known).

Applications are built using whatever language is relevant to the domain in question.  However due to their ubiquitous nature, minimal run-time, general purpose applicability, high performance, extensibility via libraries, and the sheer body of practitioners, C, and C++ are prevalent.

On Windows C++ is likely to be used more often than C for large scale commercial applications, in part due to the fact that with the release of Visual C++ and MFC in the early 1990's, Microsoft made it their preferred development language for Windows.  With the release of the .NET framework however, the preferred development language is less of an issue, and C#, VB.NET, C++/CLI and other .NET languages may be used, but few major consumer applications that I am aware of yet use .NET (and if you compare the performance of say the excellent but slow Paint.NET with PhotoShop Elements for example, you can probably see why!), it is used extensively however in bespoke application development (banking sector for example, where the client interface performance is less of an issue).

C is still commonly used on Linux applications.  Linux itself is written in C, and its primary API is a C interface.  There are plenty of C++ based application interfaces and libraries however, especially for GUI interfaces such as KDE, WxWidgets, and Qt.

OSX and iOS applications are commonly written in Objective-C since that is Apple's preferred development language and OS API.

Android applications are typically written in Java, because the Google Android API is a Java library.  But these are not typically *"really large softwares"*[sic]

Comment: Through answer! That's what SO needs more of! Good stuff!

Comment: Just a sidenote: I don't think Photoshop would be as fast as it is if it were written in C or C++, exclusively. I'm pretty sure that performance-critical parts of it were written in assembly language so they can use CPU SIMD instructions. (So the comparison between Paint.NET and Photoshop might not be entirely fair ;-)

Comment: @nikie: Quite possibiliy, but there again, the use of processor optimised libraries such as Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives Library would make assembler unnecessary (though of course the libraries themselves are coded in assembler).  Also do not underestimiate a modern compiler's ability to optimise for SIMD when specific coding idioms are used (ref: http://www.drdobbs.com/184401611).  Moreover due to JIT compilation it is theoretically poosible for .NET to be better optimised than native code because it knows exactly what hardware it is running on.

Comment: ... additionally, Adobe have implemented Photoshop on 68000, PowerPC, and x86, to be that portable, avoiding assembler would be a good idea (and in fact Photoshop is not so blisteringly fast that I would not believe that it was entirely written in C or C++).  In Paint.NET even dragging a selection or layer is too slow to be usable if it is modestly large (such a a typical digital camera image).  You don't need assembler code to accelerate that.

Answer (score 2):

The ones you've listed are primarily written in C and C++ (with some use of Objective-C on the Mac side.) Other programs may be written in other languages. ;)

Answer (score 2):

C, C++, Objective C, as usual. You don't need a magical programming language to develop large projects. It is more a matter of management and infrastructure.

Comment: Though worth noting that Objective-C is only prevalent on Applle OSX and iOS

Answer (score 2):

Due to a need for high performance, many of these "larger" applications are written using  programming languages that allow access to system resources (memory, cpu, etc.) without many abstractions in the way, in order to allow performance optimizations. Languages that allow such access include C and C++ and in some cases, or some parts of the program may include low-level assembly language.

Languages not suited for high-performance (real or near-realtime) programming tasks due to the inclusion of machine resource access abstractions include Java, C# and Visual Basic.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't very "big" applications, Enterprise applications are sometimes mammoth ( I prefer building them in JAVA :) ). For instance an application for traffic analysis used by your telecoms operator. Anyways I know VLC is quite a "large software" and it was made using C++ and qt.

Comment: Agreed, his idea of *"really large softwares"*[sic] is a somewhat limited view.

Comment: What about the traffic analysis program?

Comment: I admit traffic analysis wasn't the best description because a simple sniffer in written in C could do that. What I meant was something like http://www.nexustelecom.com/products/nexusnetview/index.php (basically a collection of related sub-applications).To mods: I am not trying to market anything just sharing something out of what limited knowledge I have about an enterprise app. I am sure there are tons of other applications that would dwarf this one :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into Joel's article http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FiveWorlds.html Those different worlds described there have different preferences when it comes to programming languages.

As others have stated, **Shrinkwrap software** is mostly written in C++ or C nowadays, same is correct for (commercial) **Games**. I suspect you won't consider **throwaway software** as really large, and perhaps the same applies for **embedded software** (but don't underestimate the size of the source code base of a  modern navigational system).

**Internal** software systems may be sometimes much larger. There are different preferred programming languages, for example, there exist really large scale systems in the financial business sector written in COBOL. Other business sectors prefer either the Java environment or the Microsoft programming world (VB6, VBA, VB.NET, C#). And high speed numeric computations are still done with (sometimes large scale) Fortran programs.

Joel mentioned also **Web application programms**. Such software systems are often build using different programming languages for the different layers of the system. For example, Java Script or Flash/Actionscript in the browser, scripting languages like Ruby, Perl, Python or PHP on the Web application server, and some of the other languages mentioned in the *Internal* category for the backend programs.

The world which is missing is the smartphone/App market (which did not exist 2002 when Joel wrote his article). Most of those existing applications are not very "big" today due to the fact the market has only evolved for a few years.

Comment: What's the difference between your 'Web application programming' and Joel's 'Commercial web based software'? How is an App not 'Shrinkwrap' of the 'downloaded from internet' medium?

Comment: You built a time machine... in Java?! Good article, thanks Doc!

Comment: @Pete: edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: @Rafael: building a time machine was primary a hardware problem ;-)

Comment: The flux-capacitor's controller runs on embedded Java. (: